# How properly set a website and domain (with subdomains) with apache on ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, vps, subdomain

First of all, apologies for my English.

I've been reading and reading guides last week a lot hours with no success. I bought a domain + hosting but due bad performance I've got a cheap vps to use as hosting. Currently my setup is:

- A domain .com with an **A record** pointed to my **vps ip**.
- A unmanaged vps with Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bits to use as hosting for my wordpress with LAMP stack with default setup (I didn't changed any setting on apache, **using default virtualhost**).

My site works fine but I'm don't know how create subdomains with different directories. For example, my website.com files are in /var/www/html and I'd like to create subdomain.website.com with the files in other directory, let's say /var/www/subdomain.

I checked a lot tutorials and they say to create a virtual server on apache (I use webmin) and then an A record for the subdomain pointing to the server ip.

The problem is that when I enter to **subdomain.website.com** I see the **content from main domain** (/var/www/html) and not from "/var/www/subdomain"

I don't want ask you for a full guide step by step, I just need know where I need to start for achieve a subdomain with a different directory because usually I always used hosting services with tools like cpanel to create subdomains pointed to directories in 2 clicks.

I'm a full newbie with Apache/dns management.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a virtual host in Apache by creating a file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.website.com.conf`

In that file, add the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName subdomain.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.website.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now place your subdomain.website.com files at

```
/var/www/subdomain.website.com/public_html
```

Then enable the new virtual host by `sudo a2ensite subdomain.website.com`

After placing the files, if you get a 403 forbidden error, check for permissions of the DocumentRoot folder.

Refer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: I followed your steps and this time it worked!! But I don't know why it didn't worked 2 hours ago when I followed the same guide, maybe because I missed some step using webmin? This time I did it manually like you told me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess it might be due to wrong document root location.