# Set up an Angular Application on Debian which already has a Wordpress site

Tags: angular, wordpress, server, debian

I have a Debian Server which has a WordPress website up and running. A domain has been pointed out to this WordPress site.

I want to create another Angular application within Apache and point a subdomain to that Angular application

Can anyone suggest How I can do that, currently is see "www" and "www.exampledomain.com" folders in the root and "www" has the WordPress Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add another Virtual Host to the Apache. Check that answer please:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30208189/3344251

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I found out the same answer. Thank you I was new to this.